# PERL: Same server different credentials

Tags: perl, ftp

I have a secured ftp with the following credentials:

```
host: x.x.x.x
username: username1
password: password1
```

After this, I have created a directory in the ftp and secured it with a different credentials:

```
path: x.x.x.x/newDirectory/
username: username2
password: password2
```

I've been trying to access my newDirectory folder using the credentials provided with the perl code below:

```
use Net::FTP;

my $host="x.x.x.x/newDirectory/";
$ftp = Net::FTP->new->($host,Debug => 0) or die;
$ftp->login("username2",'password2') or die;
```

I have been prompted by an error "Bad hostname".

Comment: The first argument (`$host`) is the name/address of the machine (and optionally a port). What you gave isn't allowed. If you need to switch directory, there's a method you can call to do that once you're connected.

Comment: Do you know how can i access the "newDirectory" folder that has a different credentials from the server?

Answer (score 2):

Below is from the Net::FTP man page

```
   new ([ HOST ] [, OPTIONS ])
       This is the constructor for a new Net::FTP object. "HOST" is the
       name of the remote host to which an FTP connection is required.
```

The string `"x.x.x.x/newDirectory/`" is not a valid host name.

You need to log into the FTP server, then change directory to `newDirectory`. The `cwd` method is what you need to use.

```
   cwd ( [ DIR ] )
       Attempt to change directory to the directory given in $dir.  If
       $dir is "..", the FTP "CDUP" command is used to attempt to move up
       one directory. If no directory is given then an attempt is made to
       change the directory to the root directory.
```

Try doing something like this (untested)

```
use Net::FTP;

my $host="x.x.x.x";
$ftp = Net::FTP->new->($host,Debug => 0) or die;
$ftp->login("username2",'password2') or die;
$ftp->cwd("newDirectory");
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, pmqs.

I already tried this code and I cant access the host since it has a different credentials.

Comment: @Pentagon, I assume you verified that you can access the server using the command line ftp program?

Comment: @pqms, i can access the host server using the first credentials. But my problem is, I can't access the newDirectory since it has a different credentials. Do you have any way to get to the newDirectory?

Comment: I'm not clear what you've done.  How exactly did you create & secure newDirectory? If you use the commandline FTP program. how do you access newDirectory? If you can't get access to newDirectory using the FTP command, you aren't going to be able to do it via Net::FTP.